# Alternative to renderas PDF for converting an HTML to PDF in apex

Tags: apex, pdf, html, blob, blob.topdf

Is there any alternative or work around to HTML to PDF convert in apex?

Please help and provide your suggestions.

Comment: What kind of problem did you get about renderAs="pdf" with apex that dissallow to use it?
In visualforce, you can use jsPDF to generate pdf, but in apex -- external services only

Comment: I have an HTML code which I need to convert to PDF. I am looking for any alternative. Please find my question here with renderas PDF. This question thread I requested for alternative to that. Please suggest any way possible. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/107705/html-page-renderas-pdf-misplaces-alignments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although certainly not the only culprits to mucking up a straight-forward conversion from a VF markup to PDF using the "renderAs" tag... I would carefully review all your CSS or other style markups, as they tend to cause failures in the PDF rendering engine if not carefully-considered.

It is, shall we say, not so easy to get a good PDF rendering with a nice HTML markup as a starting point; not so easy to find "offending element" in your CSS, especially as nice eye-pleasing webpages tend to have lots of markup.

On numerous occasions, I have found it necessary to remove ALL of the CSS and add it back in piecemeal in order to arrive to the destination -- a fully-rendered PDF version of my page.

Comment: @Jenny @Alex@I am not sure that I understand how this constitutes a "review" when all that I have done is (effectively) "second" an answer to this questions that has been provided (and was not maligned) by Alex (see above) at this post: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/107705/html-page-renderas-pdf-misplaces-alignments

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of AppExchange packages that can generate a PDF using a template- Conga, Drawloop, and Thunderhead are three well known ones. Generally these templates are built in Word or another editor though - not HTML or Visualforce.

Document generation for most of these products is "ad-hoc" - users click on a button in Salesforce to generate the document.  But I know Conga has a workflow add-on that allows documents to be generated from a workflow rule in Salesforce, or via outbound message. This would possibly better suit your use case, as it could be massaged to be initiated from Apex.  https://www.congasphere.com/products/workflow/C_about_workflow.htm.

I'm sure other products would have similar add-ons available as well.

Comment: These days Thunderhead is known as Smart Correspond.